# Restating preposition in a conjunctive phrase to avoid ambiguity

Tags: verbs, prepositions, ambiguity, conjunctions

Take the following sentence:

- *This study analyzed how perceptions of poverty and welfare policies influence social movements in the US.*

My first interpretation, and I suspect the first interpretation for most people, is that the study analyzed how perceptions of poverty and perceptions of welfare policies influence social movements in the US. That is, it is the perception of both 'poverty' and 'welfare policies' being studied.

However, it seems that one could also read this to mean that the study analyzed perceptions of poverty and welfare policies themselves, i.e., not the perception of them, but rather the actual policies.

This leads me to want to restate the preposition so that the sentence reads, "This study analyzed how perceptions of poverty and of welfare policies influence social movements in the US", but this seems kind of awkward.

Should the preposition be restated and why or why not?

Comment: "How perceptions of poverty and welfare policies influence social movements in the US" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), where the meaning is "This study analyzed the answer to the question 'How do perceptions of poverty and welfare policies influence social movements in the US?'" Note that "how" is an adverb here.

Comment: Please write answers in the answer box. But the question here is whether it's whether the welfare polices themselves, or the perceptions of them (along with the perceptions of poverty) which influence social movements. Adding *of* might remove potential ambiguity, if indeed there is any. **That's** the point which is being asked about.

Comment: Would there be a problem if you wrote "This study analyzed how welfare policies and perceptions of poverty influence social movements in the US" or does it need to give the perceptions of poverty as the first criteria?

Comment: Doesn't seem awkward to me.

Comment: @kate That's the opposite of what he wants. That's the unwanted meaning of he ambiguous construct.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that doesn't sound awkward is to add the word "both":

> This study analyzed how perceptions of both poverty and welfare policies influence social movements in the US.

This forces "poverty and welfare policies" to be treated as a group, which "perceptions of" refers to.

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree and now feel silly for not realizing this after basically putting it in the question.

Comment: You're still left with the ambiguity 'This study analyzed how perceptions of both poverty policies and welfare policies influence social movements in the US' vs 'This study analyzed how perceptions of both welfare policies and poverty influence social movements in the US'.

Comment: I've never heard the term "poverty policies", although I can see how it could be interpreted as policies intended to address poverty. Although isn't that what welfare is? @EdwinAshworth